# copying an existing row which also copies the checkbox with its code

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, copy, texel

when I press a button my table has to be expanded with 1 row. but also a checkbox has to be copied and its code behind it. How do I do this because it doesn't work this way? the line in bold is the error.

[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastColumn As Long
    Dim chkBox As CheckBox
'Determine the last row in the active worksheet
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'Determine the last column you want to expand
    lastColumn = 7
'Insert a row above the last row
    Rows(lastRow + 1).Insert
'Copy the formulas from the last row to the new row
    Range(Cells(lastRow, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastColumn)).Copy Range(Cells(lastRow + 1, 1), Cells(lastRow + 1, lastColumn))
'Copy the last checkbox with his VBA code
    Set chkBox = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Count)
    chkBox.Copy
    ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(chkBox.Left, chkBox.Top + chkBox.Height + 5, chkBox.Width, chkBox.Height).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying the checkbox object, you can create a new one based on the existing one. Copy method used on a CheckBox object is not supported in VBA.
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastColumn As Long
Dim chkBox As CheckBox
Dim newChkBox As CheckBox
Dim chkBoxTop As Double

```
    'Determine the last row in the active worksheet
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Determine the last column you want to expand
    lastColumn = 7
    
    'Insert a row above the last row
    Rows(lastRow + 1).Insert
    
    'Copy the formulas from the last row to the new row
    Range(Cells(lastRow, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastColumn)).Copy Range(Cells(lastRow + 1, 1), Cells(lastRow + 1, lastColumn))
    
    'Create a new checkbox based on the last one
    Set chkBox = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Count)
    chkBoxTop = chkBox.Top + chkBox.Height + 5
    Set newChkBox = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(chkBox.Left, chkBoxTop, chkBox.Width, chkBox.Height)
    newChkBox.Caption = chkBox.Caption
    newChkBox.Value = chkBox.Value
    
    'Copy the checkbox code behind it
    newChkBox.OnAction = chkBox.OnAction
    
End Sub
```

Create a new checkbox based on the last checkbox, set its caption and value to be the same, and copy the code behind it.

Comment: Actually, it looks like the CheckBox object does contain the Copy method.

Comment: @Domenic You are right. Thanks for politely correcting me :)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.checkbox?view=excel-pia

Answer (score 0):

First, it seems that you don't need this line of code...

```
Rows(lastRow + 1).Insert
```

Secondly, since you're adding a new CheckBox, there's no need to copy and paste your CheckBox.  Otherwise you would be adding two new CheckBoxes, not one.

Therefore, I think your macro can be re-written as follows (you may need to adjust the value you assign to the Top property of the CheckBox) ...

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastColumn As Long
    Dim chkBox As CheckBox
    Dim newChkBox As CheckBox
'Determine the last row in the active worksheet
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'Determine the last column you want to expand
    lastColumn = 7
'Copy the formulas from the last row to the new row
    Range(Cells(lastRow, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastColumn)).Copy Cells(lastRow + 1, 1)
'Copy the last checkbox with his VBA code
    Set chkBox = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Count)
    Set newChkBox = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(chkBox.Left, chkBox.Top + chkBox.Height + 5, chkBox.Width, chkBox.Height)
    With newChkBox
        .Caption = ""
        .OnAction = chkBox.OnAction
    End With
End Sub
```

However, here's another way...

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastColumn As Long

    'Determine the last row in the active worksheet
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Determine the last column, including the column containing the checkbox
    lastColumn = 8
    
    'Copy the last row to the next row
    Range(Cells(lastRow, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastColumn)).Copy Cells(lastRow + 1, 1)
    
End Sub
```